# What is the benefit of public Certificate Authority when using SSL mutual authentication?

Tags: tls, authentication, certificates, certificate-authority, mutual

I was working the other day and I had a question come up, that I want to ask here to make sure my assumptions are correct.

In terms of SSL Mutual Authentication a self signed CA and a public CA provide the same functionality, is that assumption correct?

Besides the part that, supposedly, a public CA is stored much more securely than a private CA, the functionality part is the same, right? Meaning the client will be able to communicate with the server only if both of them have the certificates issued by the same CA and the server has access to the CA, right?

So in this situation, the man-in-the-middle attack is only possible of the attacker has access to the self-signed CA, correct?

And if all of the above assumptions are correct, what is the benefit of using a public CA for ssl mutual authentication? Is it only that it's stored very securely or is there also something else?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ThoriumBR has already given a [good answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/232643/47524).

I would add some details.

> ... and the server has access to the CA

This is sufficient, but is not the only possibility. You can also add CA certificates to the trust stores of each server. In some cases this can be disadvantage, because you cannot revoke such certificates automatically. In some cases it can be an advantage, e.g. if you want to use your own certificates, but don't have any CA server. It can also be an advantage, if you want to use PKI in your intranet and servers don't have access to the public CAs.

> what is the benefit of using a public CA ... ?

1. You don't need any configuration efforts on your servers, if you are using certificate from widely known CAs, because their certificates are usually preinstalled in the OS.
2. In case a certificate of public CA is compromised, it will be added to the public certificate revocation list. That's why your servers will automatically reject certificates signed by such CA certificate. Where as if you use your own CA or no CA at all, and if you don't have your own service for certificate revocation  list, you need some efforts to invalidate the compromised certificate: find all servers that use this certificate, remove the signing certificate from each of them.

Comment: Great add, thank you, it also has the answer to the main question of what is the advantage of the public CA in the case of ssl mutual authentication.

Answer (score 3):

> In terms of SSL Mutual Authentication a self signed CA and a public CA provide the same functionality, is that assumption correct?

Yes.

> Meaning the client will be able to communicate with the server only if both of them have the certificates issued by the same CA and the server has access to the CA, right?

No. The role of the CA is to attest that an entity holding a certificate is entitled to have it. It makes sure that nobody can get a certificate for Google, except Google. That's why a CA exists.

The CA certificate is usually shipped with your OS and your browser. After receiving any certificate, the TLS libraries will check (unless told no to check) if the certificate was issued by a trusted CA, if it's expired or revoked, and here ends the CA involvement.

Mutual authentication does not depend on a CA at all. Does not matter if a certificate is self-signed, issued by a private CA or a public one. It only depends on the certificates. If I create a certificate myself on my computer, ship it to you and you configure your server to talk to me, it's done.

> So in this situation, the man-in-the-middle attack is only possible of the attacker has access to the self-signed CA, correct?

No, a MitM attack can only be conducted if someone steals the private key of both the certificates (client AND server). If they steal the client's certificate, they can impersonate the client to the server, but not the other way around.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! And what is your answer to the main question of what is the benefit of using a public CA for ssl mutual authentication?